# Form Input Field Not Submitting Due To Input Class

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm creating an Admin Panel with the Material.io style. I ran into a problem where the form wouldn't submit. After scouring my php code for nearly 20 minutes, I found that it wasn't a PHP error at all, but a `class` attribute attached to the `input` field. When the attribute is attached, the input field won't be counted, but when I take it off, it gets counted. The only downside is it looks ugly. I didn't even know it was possible for a `class` attribute to interfere with a form, so I'm completely lost.

This **does not** work:

```
<strong></strong> <tr><td><input class="form-control" type="text" 
name="job_id" value="<?php echo $jobid; ?>" /></td>
```

This **does** work:

```
<strong></strong> <tr><td><input type="text" 
name="job_id" value="<?php echo $jobid; ?>" /></td>
```

As you can see, the only things that changed in the code was the `class` attribute. I can't figure out why it's stopping the input fields from being counted.

Comment: It seems to exclude input fields with Bootstrap classes attached to them e.g. `form-control`.

Comment: Maybe there's some JS functionality associated with the class. The quickest workaround if you're worried about styling is to either place another class in the CSS file to get all the styling: `your-workaround-class, .form-control { ... }` or you can also copy the styles from the CSS file and assign it to a new class, though this is not optimal.

Comment: @CesarCorrechel I used a variant of your answer... I went into the css file, and replaced all ".form-control" with ".control" and now my form is working. I feel like this isn't causing any harm. I have no idea why someone would code it the way they did but at least it was an easy fix that I just couldn't see.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the css file and replacing all instances of `.form-control` with `.control`, my form was working again.